# i need too array prouducts from higher to lower id (products on firebase)

Tags: flutter

```
class WildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(()=>GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        childAspectRatio: .48,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        children: productController.wild.map((ProductModel product) {
          return SingleProductWidget(product: product,);
        }).toList())
    );
  }
}



class SingleProductWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ProductModel product;

  const SingleProductWidget({Key key, this.product}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
      child:
      Column(


        children: [
    

          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
             
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) =>Material(
                  type: MaterialType.transparency,
                  child: Center(
                    child:
                    Padding(
                        padding:
                         EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:(60)),
                          child:
                          CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: product.image,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            placeholder: (context, url) => new SpinKitWave(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 53, 145), size: 30,),
                            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),// Fixes border issues
                            height: double.infinity,
                            width: double.infinity,
                          ),
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
              );
            }, // Image tapped
            child:
            CachedNetworkImage(
              //height: 220,
              //width: 140,
              imageUrl: product.image,
              placeholder: (context, url) => new SpinKitWave(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 53, 145), size: 30,),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
            ),

          ),

         
          Padding(
            padding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:(0)),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: CustomText(
                  text: "\$${product.price}",
                  size: 11,
                  weight: FontWeight.bold,),),
               
                Expanded(
                  child:SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: CustomText(
                        text: product.id,
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                        size: 14,
                        weight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                )
                 
                ),
            
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                    onPressed: () {
                      cartController.addProductToCart(product);
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[this is products , its shown from lower to higher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjXx6.jpg)